# Erro na execução do arquivo no pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

Bom dia pessoal, estou vivenciando uma situação chata da qual não estou sabendo resolver.
Ao executar o game que estou desenvolvendo a seguinte imagem aparece: [image: Erro running main]

Estava tudo bem antes, o programa estava rodando normal e hoje me aparece isso. Ao entrar em File / Settings / Build,extencions,deployment / console / python console isto aparece: [image: invalid]

Não sei ao certo o que aconteceu e como resolver, alguém aí tem alguma ideia?

Comment: você precisa colocar o path correto do python. Se vc instalou via anaconda, abra o terminal do anaconda e digite `which python` que ele vai printar o path correto. Aí basta substituir o endereço na entrada correspondente no pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Tente selecionar outro interpretador, caso não funcione, faça o download do python novamente, reinicie o pycharm (pode reiniciar a máquina em si se quiser)e tente mudar o interpretador (coloque naquele que não estava antes)

Caso não dê certo, tente colocar em "Interpreter options"

```
C:\Users\<localização do venv>\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

No meu caso por exemplo, foi:

```
C:\Users\Syri\Desktop\feitos\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

Tente aí e veja se dá certo

Espero ter ajudado!